# how to convert string to number has 19 digit without auto rounded in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, rounding

we have string input number
input="6145390195186705543"
if we want to convert to number ;java Script auto rounded this input;

(6145390195186705543)

(6145390195186705000)

Comment: `BigInt(input)` https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) (among others)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for what you are trying to achieve

```js
const myFunction = (num) => {

const length = num.length;

const result = `(${num.slice(0,16).padEnd(length, "0")})`;
return result;
};

const input="6145390195186705543";
const output = myFunction(input); 
console.log(output)
```

Comment: this answer is have rounded the string input

Comment: @mahdiyarjafari oh I see, check the edited snippet; I have done the correction